# Debugging MySQL query result. Uses count function, inner join and a sub-query

Tags: mysql

This is my query. The output looks fine except the COUNT function is returning numbers which seem totally arbitrary (e.g. 7-digit numbers where I'd expect 3-digit numbers):

```
SELECT tc.tableName, m.fieldName, COUNT(m.fieldName) 
FROM apiResult, (
    SELECT cc.surveyID, cc.fieldName
    FROM apiResult as ar 
    INNER JOIN columnConversion as cc 
    ON substring(ar.triggerName,-10)=cc.fieldID 
    ) AS m 
INNER JOIN tableConversion as tc 
ON m.surveyID=tc.surveyID 
GROUP BY tc.tableName, m.fieldName;
```

I think, for a start, that `COUNT(m.fieldName)` is probably wrong, since it doesn't correspond with `GROUP BY tc.tableName, m.fieldName`.

Here's what the query is meant to do: one of the tables in the sub-query, apiResult, has a column called 'triggerName' which contains an ID I call 'fieldID', plus a column called 'surveyID'. The tables columnConversion and tableConversion are tables which match the IDs to human readble names. So, the follow query produces the count that I want, but, I want the IDs replaced by the human readable names, hence the above query:

```
SELECT cc.surveyID, cc.fieldName, COUNT(ar.triggerName)
FROM apiResult as ar
INNER JOIN columnConversion as cc 
ON substring(ar.triggerName,-10)=cc.fieldID
GROUP BY (ar.triggerName)
```

Any ideas what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you mixing explicit and implicit joins?  You appear to have missed a `join` condition on the first table.  Well, actually, I don't think it is needed.  This should work:

```
SELECT tc.tableName, m.fieldName, COUNT(m.fieldName) 
FROM (SELECT cc.surveyID, cc.fieldName
      FROM apiResult ar INNER JOIN
           columnConversion cc 
           ON substring(ar.triggerName, -10) = cc.fieldID 
     ) m INNER JOIN
     tableConversion as tc 
     ON m.surveyID = tc.surveyID 
GROUP BY tc.tableName, m.fieldName;
```

Comment: That works, thanks. Kudos on the super quick response!